# Can Quicksort be both stable and in place?

Tags: java, data-structures, quicksort

I was wondering if you could clear up a question that I got wrong on an exam.

On the exam, the question was asked "can quick sort stable and in place".

I put yes. I know that the default implementation of quick sort is NOT stable, since it may end up swapping duplicates, but I remember reading that it can be made to be stable by taking duplicate elements and indices as an additional parameter. This requires some extra storage though, so theoretically, it would not be in place.

I still put yes because according to this G4G article, it is possible to make it stable and in-place:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stable-quicksort/. They say at some point "Making it stable either requires order N storage (as in a naive implementation) or a bit of extra logic for an in-place version."

The problem is, they do not give an implementation of this "extra logic" version. I've been scouring the web trying to find an in place AND stable implementation of quick sort to no avail, so now I'm wondering if I was actually wrong and it is not possible to be both in place and stable. Hopefully someone can clear this up. Thanks!

Comment: If you want the sort to be stable without creating and maintaining O(N) extra data about the original order of the items then I think you must somehow arrange to avoid ever moving an element past another that has the same key.  That is in fact how most stable sorts achieve their stability.  I am sure that can be done by a Quicksort partitioning function, but I doubt that it can be done by a partitioning function that completes in O(N) steps, which is necessary for overall O(N log N) behavior.

Comment: Whether a quicksort modified to have these properties is still "quicksort" is a matter of definitions. The best person to discuss the question with, and argue your case, is the instructor; bring the URL along and show your reasoning. We can't help you with that debate - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Quicksort" refers to a specific algorithm that is not stable, but is in-place.

"Can quicksort be..." is a horribly vague question, because it suggests that you could make some kind of sorting algorithm that could be referred to as "Quicksort", even though it is *not quicksort at all*, because it's *close enough*...  But of course nobody is defining how close you have to be.

The real answer is just "no", because Quicksort is not stable.

There's a good chance that the expected answer is "yes", because you were told *in class* about a way to make Quicksort stable by doing something that you wouldn't do in real life, like shifting instead of swapping during the partitioning step.